# Bringing several .net webapps together into a suite

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, installation, setup-project

I'm in a project where we're going to build a number of related but yet different webapplications. Most likely there will be different teams working on the different web apps.

There will be a number of shared components DLLs that contain commmon functionality, e.g. user management, content management. There will also be a number of web pages that need to be shared, e.g. login, navigation, error handling, user profile management, binary content as images, probably lots of other stuff, unclear at the moment. 
The key is that the applications need to be able to share pages/content as well as DLLs

We are on VS2010 and using MVC 3, with Razor.

The different applicaitons should be deployed as suite, where it all integrates nicely from the users perspective.

Pushing out the DLLs/common libraries to its own projects shouldn't be a problem, the question is how to order the webapps.

Some alternatives I see:

1. Use areas to divide the different
   applications in the suite. This may
   me a monolithic mess? where people
   may step on each other toes? Anyone
   experienced with using spaces for
   this?
2. Use separate webapps but within the
   same solution. This would provide a
   cleaner cut, but make reuse harder?
   Is it possible to reuse cshtml(aspx)
   files? How do I get these WebApps
   together in a suite. Previously
   experienced with java I've use
   sitemesh, which pretty much pulls in
   different URL from different
   WAR(WebApps) files and puts it all
   into one page with common
   navigation.
3. Use separate solution and separate webapps don't know where that would offer on top of 2.

Answer (score 1):

> There will be a number of shared components DLLs that contain commmon functionality, e.g. user management, content management.

shared components should not be a problem, but it's usually better to build a service layer and let *one team* handle services only. Otherwise it's quite easy for all teams to add features that only they need which usually ends up with a big mess.

> There will also be a number of web pages that need to be shared, e.g. login, navigation, error handling, user profile management, binary content as images, probably lots of other stuff, unclear at the moment

Same thig goes for web pages. imho it's usually not a good idea. It's better to let all web sites share the same login (single sign on) and have a http://account.yoursite.com web site where all account management is done.

> the question is how to order the webapps.

subdomains. Single sig on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Agree with you first comment.

Is there a technique in asp.net to bring the apps toghether in the suite, with common navigation, I assume in this case I would have to build a separate webapp for navigation.

Comment: Theres one more thing I worry about, the dependencies on the service layer and its versions when it is managed at several places/WebApps.

Comment: Regarding navigation: Put all menu items along with the required role in a database